# Check if connection exists to a flat database in Matlab

Tags: database, matlab, flat

I have used Postgres and love its way to handle the database connection.
I have to use now Matlab and Physionet's flat database system to retrieve data.
However, I do not understand the logic in some cases, like in [ptbdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369081/access-database-in-physionets-ptbdb-by-matlab).

**How can you check if a connection exists to a database in Matlab?**

**How can you monitor what the system is doing when connecting to the database?**
It would be very nice to be able to ping the system or something like that to know what is the problem. I get no information now what is the problem.

Comment: Since you're using a third-party package, as far as I can see, I don't see how there should be a general "matlab-solution" for this. From reading the error message, I'd suggest to have a look at the responsible code and see if there's a "getConnection" or "connect(...)" line that is executed successfully before your error message...

Comment: @sebastian I have not found any code about "getConnection" or "connect". They use some other name for the command to do it. They retrieving data from flat database, which is a very slow process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection was disconnected continuously because it was not secure. 
The topic is about secure connection between Matlab and PostgreSQL, which is undocumented widely, for instance, discussed [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/secure-ssl-connection-between-matlab-and-postgresql#more-6318) about *Secure SSL connection between Matlab and PostgreSQL*.

### Summary of the blog [post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/secure-ssl-connection-between-matlab-and-postgresql#more-6318)

Make appropriate changes in

1. Generate certificate for the server; diseserver.csr, root.crt; postgreSQL directry (diseserver.key, diseserver.crt, and root.crt); please see more precisely [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/secure-ssl-connection-between-matlab-and-postgresql#more-6318)
2. postgresql.conf
3. pg_hba.conf
4. generate client certificates
5. convert key to *pkcs8* format
6. check correct version of *JDBC driver*
7. check client certificate
8. `dbtest.m`

Certificate for the server

```
$openssl req -out diseserver.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout diseserver.key
```

postgresql.conf

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = 'diseserver.crt'  # (change requires restart)
ssl_key_file  = 'diseserver.key'  # (change requires restart)
ssl_ca_file   = 'root.crt'        # (change requires restart)
```

pg_hba.conf

```
hostnossl  all    all   0.0.0.0/0   reject
hostssl  mytable  all   0.0.0.0/0   cert map=ssl clientcert=1
```

Generate client certificates

```
$mkdir ~/.postgresql
$cd ~/.postgresql
$openssl req -out postgresql.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout postgresql.key
```

Convert key to *pkcs8* format

```
$openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in postgresql.key -out postgresql.pk8 -nocrypt
```

Check client certificate

```
jdbc:postgresql://diseserver.mydomain.org/mytable?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory&sslmode=verify-full&
```

`dbtest.m` matlab function

```
function dbtest
   driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver';
   [~,username] = system('whoami');
   url = 'jdbc:postgresql://diseserver.mydomain.org/mytable?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory&sslmode=verify-full&';
   myconn = database('mytable', username, '', driver, url);
   if ~isempty(myconn.Message)
      fprintf(2,'%s\n', myconn.Message);
   else
      fprintf(1, 'Connected!\n');
   end
end
```