# Access database in Physionet's ptbdb by Matlab

Tags: database, matlab

I set up the system first by

```
[old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
wfdb_url='http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-3.zip';
[filestr,status] = urlwrite(wfdb_url,'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-3.zip');
unzip('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-3.zip');
cd mcode
addpath(pwd);savepath
```

I am trying to read databases from [Physionet](http://www.physionet.org/).
I have successfully reached one database *mitdb* by

```
[tm,sig]=rdsamp('mitdb/100',1)
```

but I want to reach the database [ptbdb](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/ptbdb/) unsuccessfully by

```
[tm,sig]=rdsamp('ptbdb/100',1)
```

and get the error

```
Warning: Could not get signal information. Attempting to read signal without buffering. 
> In rdsamp at 107 
Error: Cannot convert to double: 
init: can't open header for record ptbdb/100
Error using rdsamp (line 145)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot convert
    at org.physionet.wfdb.Wfdbexec.execToDoubleArray(Unknown Source)
```

The first error message refers to these lines in *rdsamp.m*:

```
if(isempty(N))
    [siginfo,~]=wfdbdesc(recordName);
    if(~isempty(siginfo))
        N=siginfo(1).LengthSamples;
    else
        warning('Could not get signal information. Attempting to read signal without buffering.')
    end
end
```

This line `if(~isempty(siginfo))` is false means that the **siginfo** is empty that is there is no signal. **Why?** No access to the database, I think.
I think other errors follow from it.
So the error must follow from this line

```
[siginfo,~]=wfdbdesc(recordName);
```

**What does the snake mean here in the brackets?**

**How can you get data from ptbdb by Matlab?**

So

**Does this error mean that the connection cannot be established to the database?**
or
**that there does not exists such data in the database?**

It would be very nice to know how you can check if you have connection to the database like in Postrgres. It would be much easier to debug.

Comment: flagged it. I don't have enough reps. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `physionetdb("ptdb",1)` it will download the files to your computer. You will then be able to see the available records in the `<current-dir>/ptdb/`

Source: [physionetdb function documentation](http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/html/physionetdb.html). You are interested in the DoBatchDownload parameter.

After downloading it, I believe every command from the toolbox will check if you have the files locally before fetching from the server (as long as you give the function the correct path to the local files).

Comment: You seem to be right. It is now generating the files giving the output *Making directory: mitdb to store record files*. What is your source? How can you then use these locally downloaded files in your system?

Comment: I´ve updated the answer with the link to the command documentation.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer and correction in the thread! I do not like that the toolbox does not give warning if not using local storage of files. I want to  minimise the recurrent connection of online Physionet databases because they slow my systems down much. I want to prevent the online access for now to understand my mistakes. I opened a new thread about the thing here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36850459/54964 Do you have any ideas about how to manage such a local storage? Etc many projects using same data. Any dbpath possible? My Matlab script is in different location.

Comment: I opened a ticket about setting dbpath here https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/117 because I cannot find the default way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data unit "100" does not exist in the database *ptbdb*.

I run finally successfully after waiting 35 minutes with 100Mb cable broadband:

```
db_list = physionetdb('ptbdb')
```

and get not complete data finally to the patient 54 - there should be 294 patients.

```
'ptbdb/patient001/s0014lre' 'ptbdb/patient001/s0014lre' ... cut ...
```

The main developer, Ikaro's' answer helped me to wait so long:

> ```
> The WFDB Toolbox connects to PhysioNet's file server. The databases
> accessible through the WFDB Toolbox are not SQL database, they consist
> of flat files. The error message that you are getting regarding the
> ptdb/100 database is because you are attempting to get a record that
> does not exist on the database.
> ```
>
> For more information on a particular database or record in PhysioNet
>   please type:
>
> help physionetdb
>
> and
>
> physionetdb('ptdb')

This flat file system is really a bottle neck in the system.
It would be a good time to change to SQL.

Comment: I sent a question to the developers to use the offline data instead of internet to retrieve the data. I have the data dump in my system. Probably, it solves some of the problem.